# elasticsearch 1.6 elasticsearch command and code is not working in jdk11

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-1.6.0

i am using `elasticsearch-1.6` its working fine when i have `java 1.8` sbt version `0.13` and scala version `2.11.1` after then i updated to java version

```
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

sbt  `1.2.8` and scala `2.12.8` 
when i initiate elasticsearch command

```
:/opt/elasticsearch-1.6.0/bin$ elasticsearch
```

it shows

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

and when i try to create a client in the code

```
val clusterName=config.getString("es.clusterName")
   val host=config.getString("es.host")

val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
     client = new TransportClient(settings);
     client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(host,9300));
```

and here is the config file

```
es.clusterName="myCluster"
es.host="172.18.0.2"
```

i got the following exceptions

```
org.elasticsearch.common.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.elasticsearch.cache.recycler.PageCacheRecycler.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.cache.recycler.PageCacheRecycler
    for parameter 0 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigArrays.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigArrays
    for parameter 3 at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport
  while locating org.elasticsearch.transport.Transport
    for parameter 1 at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.elasticsearch.common.unit.MemorySizeValue.parseBytesSizeValueOrHeapRatio(MemorySizeValue.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings.getAsMemory(ImmutableSettings.java:401)
    at org.elasticsearch.cache.recycler.PageCacheRecycler.<init>(PageCacheRecycler.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:52)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:200)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:830)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.loadEagerSingletons(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.injectDynamically(InjectorBuilder.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:110)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:125)
    at models.ElasticSearchConnectionInfo$.createClient(ElasticSearchConnectionInfo.scala:31)
    at models.ElasticSearchConnectionInfo$.getClient(ElasticSearchConnectionInfo.scala:41)
    at esconnection.ESconnectionStart.ESconStart(ESconnectionStart.scala:9)
    at com.ifkaar.hazelcastserver.HazelcastServer.main(HazelcastServer.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:98)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:92)
    at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:68)
    at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:80)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:253)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Boot class path mechanism is not supported
    at java.management/sun.management.RuntimeImpl.getBootClassPath(RuntimeImpl.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm.JvmInfo.<clinit>(JvmInfo.java:77)
    ... 60 more

2) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm.JvmInfo
  at org.elasticsearch.cache.recycler.PageCacheRecycler.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.cache.recycler.PageCacheRecycler
    for parameter 0 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigArrays.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigArrays
    for parameter 3 at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport
  while locating org.elasticsearch.transport.Transport
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm.JvmInfo
    at org.elasticsearch.common.unit.MemorySizeValue.parseBytesSizeValueOrHeapRatio(MemorySizeValue.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings.getAsMemory(ImmutableSettings.java:401)
    at org.elasticsearch.cache.recycler.PageCacheRecycler.<init>(PageCacheRecycler.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:52)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:200)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:830)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.loadEagerSingletons(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.injectDynamically(InjectorBuilder.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:110)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:125)
    at models.ElasticSearchConnectionInfo$.createClient(ElasticSearchConnectionInfo.scala:31)
    at models.ElasticSearchConnectionInfo$.getClient(ElasticSearchConnectionInfo.scala:41)
    at esconnection.ESconnectionStart.ESconStart(ESconnectionStart.scala:9)
    at com.ifkaar.hazelcastserver.HazelcastServer.main(HazelcastServer.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:98)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:92)
    at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:68)
    at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:80)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:253)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

also i have a doubt that my /root folder is running low space, so is that possible that was causing the issue ?if not what else is wrong here please guide

Comment: you can free up some space and try, also if possible try to use the latest version of ES

Comment: elasticsearch 1.6 end-of-lifed three years ago. You need to upgrade to something less ancient

Comment: jdk 11 is supported by 6.5 (!) and up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch 1.6.x is not supported on Oracle/OpenJDK 11. You will need to either downgrade your Java installation or install the latest patch version of JVM 8 alongside JVM 11 to try and run Elasticsearch 1.6.x. [See the JVM / Elasticsearch compatibility matrix.](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_jvm)

Running both an outdated JVM and an outdated Elasticsearch instance can cause security problems and other headaches, so I highly recommend upgrading both to their latest versions if you can. You'll need to reindex your data, at least going from 1.6 to 7.